# Can't locate object method via package, even though I'm not using methods

Tags: methods, runtime-error, perl

I have code roughly like this:

```
sub define_pattern { push @Internal::patterns, $_[0]; }

package Internal {
    our @patterns = ();

    sub func { define_pattern { pattern => '(.*)\.c$' }; }
}

Internal::func;
```

(Of course, this is a simplified version!) Now, when I run it, it outputs:

```
Can't locate object method "define_pattern" via package "pattern" (perhaps you forgot to load "pattern"?) at x.pl line 6.
```

I already Googled this error and looked at several similar SO questions, but none of them seem to have the solution to this. Why does Perl think `define_pattern` is a method and `pattern` is a package? I thought this error only occurred when using `->` like `pattern->define_method`.

Comment: What is your `define_pattern` meant to be?  You are invoking it with curlies (and not qualifying it btw.)

Comment: @zdim It's normally a bit longer, but it essentially does what it shows, except the full version does some checking and modification of the input parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the sub `define_pattern` need be invoked with `()` this would only be a syntax error, except for the indirect object syntax that kicks in and  tries to run it as a method on an object supposedly computed inside the `{}` block (as explained in ThisSuitIsBlackNot's answer).

However, I'd also change namespaces properly, and you need to qualify the call to `define_pattern`.  Since there is a restriction that the package lives in the same compilation unit we leave it at that

```
use warnings;
use strict;

package Internal;
our @patterns;
sub func { 
    main::define_pattern ( pattern => qr/(.*)\.c$/ );
}

package main;

Internal::func;

my @array = @Internal::patterns;

print "Copied onto \@array: |@array|\n";

sub define_pattern { 
  my %in = @_;
  push @Internal::patterns, $in{'pattern'}; 
}
#sub define_pattern { push @Internal::patterns, $_[0]; }
```

*Note*. The `Internal::func` call is needed to trigger the action of `define_pattern` so any use of the global `@Internal::patterns` has to come *after* that call (in this code). So they are switched around. Regex is built using `qr`. The sub is changed (minimally) so to actually store the pattern in the global array.  Code prints the specified pattern:

```
Copied onto @array: |(?-xism:(.*)\.c$)|
```

To be able to at least store patterns dynamically, with minimal changes

```
package Internal;
our @patterns;
sub func {
    my ($arg) = @_;
    main::define_pattern ( pattern => qr/$arg/ );
}

package main;

Internal::func('(.*)\.c$/');
```

Comment: No; it's in the same file. There's a *long* list of really messy reasons, but just assume that it's necessary...

Comment: Also, the code *compiles*, but it doesn't *run*. The error is in `Internal::func`.

Answer (score 4):

You're being bitten by [indirect object syntax](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.9/perlobj.html#Indirect-Object-Syntax). Perl interprets this:

```
define_pattern { pattern => '(.*)\.c$' };
```

as the name of a method followed by a block that returns the invocant. You can see this with the `indirect` pragma:

```
no indirect;

sub define_pattern { push @Internal::patterns, $_[0]; }

package Internal {
    our @patterns = ();

    sub func { define_pattern { pattern => '(.*)\.c$' }; }
}
```

Output:

```
Indirect call of method "define_pattern" on a block at foo line 10.
```

Why does the parser think that `define_pattern` is a method and not a regular subroutine? Because there's no subroutine named `define_pattern` in the `Internal` package; you defined it in `main`.

If you call a non-exported subroutine from another package, you have to use the fully-qualified subroutine name:

```
main::define_pattern({ pattern => '(.*)\.c$' });
```

(The parentheses are optional if `define_pattern` is declared before you call it.)